# How to "Open a new window in GNU/Screen" by running a command?

Tags: gnu-screen

I want to know how to accomplish this: Open a new window in GNU/screen, by running a command.

Here's what I want to do:
I uses GNU/screen daily. My laptop runs in UTF-8 locale, and I need to ssh to some specific servers which runs in GBK locale.
Normally I need to change encoding *after* I ssh to the server. I'm looking for an automatic way, which allows me just `alias` a series of command and then start the `ssh GBK_LOCALE_SERVER` command in another GBK-encoding GNU/screen window

Answer (score 7, accepted):

/usr/bin/screen knows it's running within a screen session; if you pass it a command as an argument, it will run that command in a new tab.

So, from a shell within screen, you can just run

```
screen ssh GBK_LOCALE_SERVER
```

and the result will appear in a new window in the current screen.